# Angular can't find custom module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular7, angular-module

I'm trying to convert my Angular 7 app to use modules so that I get lazy loading. When I run with modules the browser says

> core.js:18374 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './orders/orders.module'
>   Error: Cannot find module './orders/orders.module'

I'm not sure why that's happening as the `.../src/app/orders/orders.module.ts` file definitely exists. Originally I just had a `.../src/app/orders` directory and in it multiple components.  To implement the modules I did this

```
% mv src/app/orders orders
% ng g m orders --routing
% mv orders/* src/app/orders
```

I then removed all the routes from `app-routing.module.ts` and replaced it with this, so that by default when you go to the app it takes you to the orders list.

```js
{
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
},
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'orders',
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

And then `orders-routing.module.ts` looks like so:

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {OrderEditComponent} from './order-edit/order-edit.component';
import {OrderListComponent} from './order-list/order-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'edit', component: OrderEditComponent},
    {path: 'byMonth', component: OrderListComponent},
    {path: '', component: OrderListComponent},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OrdersRoutingModule {
}
```

orders.module looks like so:

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

import {OrdersRoutingModule} from './orders-routing.module';
import {OrderListComponent} from './order-list/order-list.component';
import {OrderEditComponent} from './order-edit/order-edit.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        OrderListComponent,
        OrderEditComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        OrdersRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class OrdersModule {
}
```

You can see the files exist in the proper spot.

[image]

Comment: please provide the tree directory and module routing file.

Comment: I updated the question to show that data.

Comment: it's possible to make a screenshot of the tree file from the explorer menu?.

Comment: What specifically are you wanting to see?  There's a ton of other stuff there.

Comment: OK, I think that's what you're wanting, now pasted into the question.

Comment: great, can you provide the order.module

Comment: Pretty soon you're gonna ask me to upload the whole project :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185948/discussion-between-yoarthur-and-gargoyle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i suggest create a new project using angular CLI, copy app folder, paste in the new project, and re-run it.

Answer (score 0):

Import OrdersModule in the root module.